# Как получить ключ md5, знаяя код и исходную строку?

Tags: шифрование, md5

Пусть есть исходная строка S.
Пусть есть закодированная строка S'.
Можно ли, располагая этими данными узнать ключ md5?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что используя строку с md5 хэшем, кто то закодировал строку и Вам известна начальная строка и закодированная. А узнать хочется собственно ключ - md5 строку?

Comment: Да и этот кто-то это я. Поэтому мне интересно, сможет ли кто-нибудь подобрать ключ, чтобы расшивровать строку, которую я закодировал. Вот

Comment: Если алгоритм шифрования неизвестный, то сложно. Но реально - потому что криптоаналитик может угадать алгоритм.
Вообще то, алгоритмы шифрования, для которых неизвестный алгоритм хороши до тех пор, пока кто то не узнает алгоритм.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

md5 одностороннее шифрование. ключа нет. если нужен ключ при шифровании вам к sha,
Вы имеете ввиду: например есть строка "привет" и md5 от нее 5ba7ce89211c0fd2e74f8d5910562738 и есть ли ключ? ключ и будет привет :) и я полностью уверен что шифрование односторонее. конечно есть способы его разшифровать но это ооочено геморно

Comment: это ооочено геморно - сказал человек ничего не знающий и не понимающий в этом...

Comment: Относится ко всем кто ставит плюсы этому бреду - это бред :DDD

Comment: аргументируйте почему это бред.

Comment: Потомучто md5 хеши в настоящее время подбираются на ура, любой юзер владеющий компом на среднем уровне, гуглом и мозгом может найти аргументы. Я бы, конечно, мог бы расписать что да как, но это будет больше похоже на статью, причем не маленькую, чем на комментарий...

Comment: Проверка online ресурса по "расшифровке" md5 (http://md5list.ru/) для хэша 483b855715a28b47217a74927601a416 (строка 'xaxa') привела к результату: ***К сожалению, такой хэш в базе отсутствует.***

Интересно, остальные "на ура" лучше ???

Comment: avp, ну тут походу числовые и словарные хеши работают только. )))

Comment: если вы такой мастер в брутах хешей, это круто, но это не означает что написан бред, тем более уже давно никто не использует просто хеш от строки, еще очень много соли присутсвует.

Comment: @Arni, да наверняка словарь, просто это к тому, что "на ура" md5 не подбирается. 

Можно быстро подобрать (как Вы указали в URL своем комментарии) с помощью крутой видео-карты для пароля из 5-6 символов. 

Наверное за несколько часов можно найти коллизию для произвольного хэша. Но **программу (исходник)**, вычисляющую эти коллизии я через google отыскать не смог.

Comment: avp, если она вас интересует я попрошу ребят чтобы дали. Но она предназначена для подключения к мобильному устройству, далее я не особо в курсе что с нее еще можно вытянуть. Если вам интересно свяжитесь со мной я вам ее возьму у ребят. Она есть. Исходник не обещаю, но вроде был где-то.

Comment: Спасибо, @Arni, но наверное не стоит. Интерес к этому предмету  умозрительный.

Answer (score 2):

Самым классическим методом является метод перебора. В очередности переберем все возможные строки, сравнивая с исходной. Еще одним вариантом, есть хранение в базе данных уже готовых хешей и их исходных строк. Поиск соответствия, это вопрос секундный. Но и размеры таких баз впечатляют. Вероятность того что мы обнаружим это соответствие равна 100%, это вопрос времени. Но, также существует вероятность того, что мы обнаружим и такое.

S1h = md5(S); S2h = md5(S); S1h = S2h;

Это называется коллизия, или как еще любят называть, парадокс о днях рождения.

У алгоритма md5 есть целый ряд уязвимость. 2 в степени 64 оцениваний функции хеширования, позволяет выявить эти самые коллизии. А это достаточно просто для современных компьютеров.

Именно поэтому, md5 в чистом виде, не используется ни на одной более менее хорошо защищенной системе.

Comment: @arni, 2^64 это **очень** большое число. 

А вот об определении длины, пожалуйста, поподробнее (каким образом достаточно просто ее найти).

Comment: avp, верное замечание, это я сморозил перепутав немного с другим. Специально взял даже учебник чтобы уточнить. Прошу меня извинить, материал проходил довольно таки давно, и там кокраз была описана проблема, что именно добавить недостающую часть строки это всетаки достаточно сложно. Про  2^64, я с вами не согласен. Это уже давно не показатель. Используя ресурсы современных видо-карт, эта планка достаточно легко преодолима. Да и http://cryptography.hyperlink.cz/md5/MD5_collisions.pdf вроде все правильно но я лично не проверял.

Comment: @Arni, Спасибо, прочитал Вашу ссылку. Вывод: коллизия ищется на современном PC за несколько часов. 

В какой степени эти алгоритмы переносимы на видео-карты (векторно-параллельные вычисления, насколько я понимаю) вопрос открытый.

----

По поводу 2^64. В статье идет речь об оценке сложности алгоритма  порядка 2^43. Согласитесь, разница примерно в миллион раз.

Comment: Это вам информация от моих бывших коллег и братцев по ремонту мобильных телефонов. )) Я уже тогда был не при делах, но код доступа к Nokia вскрывался на моих глазах за сутки. А там поверьте было не 2^64 и не md5

http://www.golubev.com/gpuest.htm